# Why is code coverage non-zero for mocked JS imports in Vitest/Jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, mocking, vitest

I would like to test a JS file (`index.js`) using Vitest.
The file imports an ES6 class (`service.js`), instantiates it and calls a function on it. I am mocking the service in `index.spec.js` using `vi.mock` and `vi.spyOn`. I know that similar functionality is availble in Jest on which Vitest is based.

index.js

```
import Service from './service';

export const indexFn = () => {
    return new Service().serviceFn();
}
```

service.js

```
export default class Service {
    serviceFn() {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

index.spec.js

```
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';
import { indexFn } from './index';
import Service from './service';

vi.mock('./service');

describe('suite', () => {
    it('tests', () => {
        const mockedReturn = 'mockedReturn';
        vi.spyOn(Service.prototype, 'serviceFn').mockReturnValue(mockedReturn);
        expect(indexFn()).toBe(mockedReturn);
    });
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "name": "jest-non-zero-coverage",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.25.1",
    "vitest": "^0.25.1"
  }
}
```

If I run the tests with code coverage enabled using `npx vitest --run --coverage` I get 100% for `index.js` but the coverage report also shows me that there is non-zero code coverage for `service.js` even though I am mocking it:

| File | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All files | 80 | 100 | 0 | 80 |  |
| index.js | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |  |
| service.js | 60 | 100 | 0 | 60 | 3-4 |

How can this be? Surely, the mocking should ensure that no lines are ever covered. Are there any settings I need to adjust or are the mocks not working?

Comment: Please, post https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve instead of truncated snippets, it's unknown if there are things that could explain this

Comment: OK, I've recreated the problem in a minimal example.

Comment: `vi.mock('service')` can't affect `import Service from './service'`. They are different modules

Comment: That was clearly a typo and with `vi.mock('./service')` I have the same behaviour.

Comment: I'd suggest to debug if class constructor really runs. I think that's specific to Vitest, I expect it to work correctly in Jest. Also spyOn would not be needed as serviceFn is already a spy in stubbed class.